# Error when Asp.net website is on the server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i upload my asp.net project to my server i get the following error:

```
Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'web1.WebForm1'.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="web1.WebForm1" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Source File: /kaka/web1/WebForm1.aspx    Line: 1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [error in deploying asp.net project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364469/error-in-deploying-asp-net-project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is an asp.net web application (not website), then you need to upload your codebehind DLL as well.

If this is a website, then you need to upload your app_data directory.

Comment: i upload all the project including dll