# error in deploying asp.net project

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

> Parser Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'web1.WebForm1'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> ```
> Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="web1.WebForm1" %>
> Line 2:  
> Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
> ```
>
> Source File: /kaka/web1/WebForm1.aspx    Line: 1

Comment: What does your WebForm1.aspx.vb file look like?

Comment: Did you build the application? Is it a web site, or a web application project (does it have a .vbproj file)? Exactly how did you attempt to deploy it?

Comment: Firstly I would like say turn the autoeventwireup On and secondly until you share your segment of code in the code behind page, it will be difficult to figure out what is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the posted info, it sounds like your code behind is malformed. Your WebForm1.aspx.vb file should look something like this:

```
Namespace web1
    Partial Public Class WebForm1
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

        Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        End Sub

    End Class
End Namespace
```